Expanding function like C macros with clang libTooling
EDIT
I solved the macro expansion using boost::wave. I still need help integrating this expansion code with my MacroExpander PPCallbacks class to take advantage of the clang::Rewriter member to preprocess the source and then pass it on for further rewriting to a [clang::RecursiveASTVisitor][2].  Hopefully this should be a much easier problem to solve.  I already know how to use the PPCallback as a preorocessor with a RecursiveASTVisitor. (The idea being the MacroExpander performs the macro expansion preprocessing before the RecursiveASTVisitor adds the instrumentation, both steps involve rewriting).
Working MacroExpander code
This code unfortunately boost based.  I need to integrate this with my   MacroExpander PPCallbacks class to take advantage of the MacroExpander::mRewriter
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/wave.hpp>
#include <boost/wave/cpplexer/cpp_lex_token.hpp>
#include <boost/wave/cpplexer/cpp_lex_iterator.hpp>

int
main() {
    std::string input = R"(
#define TWO                     (2)         // object like macro
#define THREE()                 (3)         // function like macro with 0 args
#define FOUR()                  (4)         // function like macro with 0 args
#define NUMSQUARED(x)           ((x)*(x))   // function like macro with 1 arg
#define MIN(a, b)               (((a) <= (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define MAX(a, b)               (((a) >  (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define FUNC_MACRO(x)           ((x) + 1)
#define NESTED_MACRO(a, b)      (FUNC_MACRO(a) + NUMSQUARED(b) + FUNC_MACRO(FOUR()) + TWO + THREE())

#define QUEUE_NEW(name, depth)                                          \
extern const Queue name;                                                \
static void  name ## _Init(void) { Queue_Init ( &(name) ); }            \
static QCond name ## _Put(int a) { return Queue_Put ( &(name), a); }    \
static int   name ## _Get(void) { return Queue_Get ( &(name) ); }       \
static QCond name ## _Status(void) { return Queue_Status ( &(name) ); } \
static int   name ## _Base[depth];                                      \
static QHeader name ## _Hdr;                                            \
const Queue name = {                                                    \
    & name ## _Hdr,                                                     \
    depth,                                                              \
    & name ## _Base[0],                                                 \
    name ## _Init,                                                      \
    name ## _Put,                                                       \
    name ## _Get,                                                       \
    name ## _Status                                                     \
}

int main() {
    QUEUE_NEW(cdu_event_q, 40);
    int a = NESTED_MACRO(1, 2);
    int b = MIN(1, TWO);
    int c = MIN(1, 2);
    int d = MIN(1, THREE());
    int f = MIN(1, NUMSQUARED(3));
    int g = MIN(MAX(1, 2), 3);
}
)";

    using token_type = boost::wave::cpplexer::lex_token<>;
    using lex_iterator_type = boost::wave::cpplexer::lex_iterator<token_type>;
    using context_type = boost::wave::context<std::string::iterator, lex_iterator_type>;

    std::string::iterator first = input.begin();
    std::string::iterator last = input.end();

    context_type ctx(first, last, "input.cpp");
    ctx.set_language(boost::wave::support_cpp);
    std::string result;
    try {
        context_type::iterator_type it = ctx.begin();
        context_type::iterator_type end = ctx.end();

        while (it != end) {
            result += std::string((*it).get_value().begin(), (*it).get_value().end());
            ++it;
        }
    } catch (const boost::wave::cpp_exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Wave error: " << e.description() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Standard exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Expanded output:\n" << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Program Output
Expanded output:
int main() {
extern const Queue cdu_event_q; static void cdu_event_q_Init(void) { Queue_Init ( &(cdu_event_q) ); } static QCond cdu_event_q_Put(int a) { return Queue_Put ( &(cdu_event_q), a); } static int cdu_event_q_Get(void) { return Queue_Get ( &(cdu_event_q) ); } static QCond cdu_event_q_Status(void) { return Queue_Status ( &(cdu_event_q) ); } static int cdu_event_q_Base[ 40]; static QHeader cdu_event_q_Hdr; const Queue cdu_event_q = { & cdu_event_q_Hdr, 40, & cdu_event_q_Base[0], cdu_event_q_Init, cdu_event_q_Put, cdu_event_q_Get, cdu_event_q_Status };
int a = (((1) + 1) + (( 2)*( 2)) + (((4)) + 1) + (2) + (3));
int b = (((1) <= ( (2))) ? (1) : ( (2)));
int c = (((1) <= ( 2)) ? (1) : ( 2));
int d = (((1) <= ( (3))) ? (1) : ( (3)));
int f = (((1) <= ( ((3)*(3)))) ? (1) : ( ((3)*(3))));
int g = ((((((1) > ( 2)) ? (1) : ( 2))) <= ( 3)) ? ((((1) > ( 2)) ? (1) : ( 2))) : ( 3));
}

The problem
Many IDE's (Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code &  Eclipse) have the ability to show 'C' macro expansions while hovering over the macros in the source code.
I have been struggling to achieve something similar with a libTooling based application that I am developing to rewrite and instrument 'C' source code.
As far as macros go, most of the expansion logic in my MacroExpander is working, however I am struggling with how to correctly handle macro argument parameters - especially when the argument is also an unexpanded macro that requres expansion.
Correctly using clang::PPCallbacks relies on the user having a very detailed low-level knowledge of the innards of both Clang and the clang::Preprocessor (unfortunately, I am not that familiar).  I purchased a copy of 'LLVM Techniques, Tips, and Best Practices' by Min-Yih Hsu with source code examples.  This is an excellent book (Chapter 6 'Extending the Preprocessor' contains PPCallbacks examples). however the examples fall very short of something useful for expanding function like or nested macros.
Consider the following macros:
#define TWO                     (2)  // object like macro
#define THREE()                 (3)  // function like macro with 0 args
#define NUMBER(x)               (x)  // function like macro with 1 arg
#define MIN(a, b)               (((a) <= (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define MAX(a, b)               (((a) >  (b)) ? (a) : (b))

Going from simple to more complex, I would like to expand the following macro invocations:
MIN(1, 2);
MIN(1, TWO);
MIN(1, THREE());
MIN(1, NUMBER(3));
MIN(MAX(1, 2), 3);

The Incomplete Algorithm
From various tests, the PPCallbacks::MacroExpands method is called every time a macro is expanded in the source.  If the macro in the source is a function-like macro and any function arguments are also macros, these arguments will each trigger a separate callback to PPCallbacks::MacroExpands after the outermost macro has completed.  Since I need to rewrite the code without overlaps, I need a way of postponing and consolidating the rewrites to whenever the last unexpanded macro has been expanded.
Each time the PPCallbacks::MacroExpands method is called whenever a macro is expanded.  The MacroExpands code consists of 2 blocks (one that handles function-like macro expansion and the else that handles simple object-like macro expansion (for ex. #define FOO 3).  The code uses the range parameter's expansion location and the macro name as a key to a std::map.  The value side of the map, maintains the list of expanded parameters and unexpanded macro definitions (I need to maintain some order here to unpack when all parameters have been expanded.. later).
I am mainly having trouble with the function-like expansion logic as shown in the if (MI->isFunctionLike()) {...} code block.  The way I handle this is that I loop over the argument names/values.  There should be an identical number of names & values.  So for example when expanding the macro MIN(1, 2) I end up with a std::map<string, string> macroParamInfo variable containing:
{{"a","1"}, {"b","2"}}.

Later on, I will substitute these name(identifier)/value pairs while iterating over the tokens of the macro.
The next step (after collecting the above 'identifier-name/value' pairs in macroParamInfo) involves iterating over the MD.getMacroInfo()->tokens() searching for a mix of token identifiers (which require further expansion), macro pasting & stringification operators (## & #), and few other token types while at the same time expanding the text to a macroBody variable.  In the case of being called to expand the macro MIN(1, 2) in the C code, the loop: for (const auto next : MI->tokens()) {...} will iterate over 19 individual tokens that constitute the MIN macro (note: <= is a single token), i.e:
'(', '(', '(', 'a', ')', '<=', '(', 'b', ')', ')', '?', '(', 'a', ')', ':', '(', 'b', ')' & finally ')'
Expanding these tokens involves appending each token in turn to the macroBody variable and replacing identifiers (in this case a & b) with the corresponding values from the macroParamInfo.  In the case of MIN(1, 2), this gets correctly expanded to (((1)<=(2))?(1):(2)).  All good so far as this is a normal type of expansion (I also successfully tested this for some complicated macro expansions containing ## & # operators and those also expand successfully.
More Complicated Example
Things get a bit more complicated when we pass other unexpanded macros in as parameters.  As described in the first paragraph of the algorithm, these nested macro arguments will be called separately after the parent macro's MacroExpands callback has completed. Let's go through the MIN(1, TWO) example as it contains a simple parameterless macro argument that should expand to '2'.
In the first pass through MacroExpander::MacroExpands, just as before, we will evaluate the same information in MIN's macroArgNames (i.e. "a" & "b"), however as we go through the macro argument loop, as the second argument TWO is also a macro, it will trigger the logic in if (Args->ArgNeedsPreexpansion(Tok, mPP)) {..}.  This is where we save definition of the TWO macro to the rMacroDefs map. In this case the 'rMacroDefs[ArgMacroName] = parameter' assignment results in rMacroDefs containing {"TWO", "(2)"} and the rExpanded variable contains the first expanded parameter "1".  The next time the MacroExpander::MacroExpands is called is to expand the TWO macro.
This is where I need help.
The partially working and compiling source is as follows:
The code
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <clang/Lex/PPCallbacks.h>
#include <clang/Lex/MacroArgs.h>
#include <clang/Lex/Preprocessor.h>
#include <clang/Tooling/Core/Replacement.h>
#include <clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h>
#include <clang/Tooling/Tooling.h>
#include <clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h>
#include <clang/Rewrite/Core/Rewriter.h>

using namespace llvm;
using namespace clang::driver;
using namespace clang::tooling;

namespace {
    llvm::cl::OptionCategory MyToolCategory("my-tool options");
}

namespace util {
    namespace rv = ranges::views;
    inline constexpr auto trim_front = rv::drop_while(::isspace);
    inline constexpr auto trim_back = rv::reverse | trim_front | rv::reverse;
    inline constexpr auto trim = trim_front | trim_back;

    inline std::string trim_str(const std::string& s) {
        return s | trim | ranges::to<std::string>;
    }

    inline std::vector<std::string> split (std::string& s, const char delim) {
        return ranges::actions::split(s, delim);
    }
}

/**
 * The <code>MacroExpander</code> class overrides the
 * <code>MacroExpands</code> method from
 * <code>clang::PPCallbacks</code> to rewrite expanded macros
 * back into the source before instrumentation.
 *
 * <p>As macros are expanded in the code, the
 * <code>MacroExpands</code> function differentiates between
 * function-like and object-like macros, handling their
 * expansion differently. For function-like macros,
 * it constructs a map of macro parameter names to their values
 * and uses this map to replace the macro invocation in the
 * source code with the expanded macro body, substituting
 * parameter references with their corresponding values.
 */
class MacroExpander : public clang::PPCallbacks {
public:
    /**
    * Explicit constructor.
    *
    * <p>Change Preprocessor options via the returned reference returned by
    * <code>mPP.getPreprocessorOpts</code>() if necessary.
    *
    * @param rPP       [in] clang Preprocessor.
    * @param rRewriter [in] non const rewriter reference.
    */
    explicit MacroExpander(clang::Preprocessor &rPP, clang::Rewriter &rRewriter)
        : mPP(rPP)
        , mRewriter(rRewriter)
    {}

    /**
     * Hook that gets called as macros are expanded in the C code.
     *
     * @param MacroNameTok [in] The token representing the macro name.
     * @param MD           [in] Macro Definition containing all the
     *                     info about the type of macro and its
     *                     parameters.
     * @param Range        [in] Source range of the macro.
     * @param Args         [in] Optional macro arguments.
     */
    void MacroExpands(
        const clang::Token& MacroNameTok,
        const clang::MacroDefinition& MD, clang::SourceRange Range,
        const clang::MacroArgs* Args) override {
        // Get the macro name
        const auto& SM = mPP.getSourceManager();
        const auto expansionRange = SM.getExpansionRange(Range);
        auto foo = locStr(expansionRange.getBegin());
        const auto MacroName = mPP.getSpelling(MacroNameTok);
        llvm::errs() << "Expanding macro: " << MacroName << "\n";
        const auto MI = MD.getMacroInfo();

        // not sure why these variables are not true when expanding the macros
        const auto bMacroBodyExpansion = SM.isMacroBodyExpansion(Range.getBegin());
        const auto bMacroArgExpansion = SM.isMacroArgExpansion(Range.getBegin());

        // Find the current macro we are expanding using
        // the 'macro-name/expansion-location' key.
        using MacroKey = std::pair<std::string, clang::SourceLocation>;
        using MacroDefs = std::map<std::string, std::string>;

        // Mapping from key: <macro-name, expansion-location> and to expanded args
        static std::map<MacroKey, std::pair<std::vector<std::string>, MacroDefs>> gMacroExpansionInfo;
        const MacroKey macroKey = { MacroName, expansionRange.getBegin() };

        // Initialize the expanded macro parameter to an
        // empty list while we iterate over the parameters.
        if (!gMacroExpansionInfo.contains(macroKey)) {
            gMacroExpansionInfo[macroKey] = {};
        }

        // Get the macro body
        std::string macroBody;
        if (MI->isFunctionLike()) {
            // Expand the parameters
            std::vector<std::string> macroArgNames;
            for (const auto next : MI->params()) {
                macroArgNames.emplace_back(next->getName().str());
            }
            auto& [rExpandedArgs, rMacroDefs] = gMacroExpansionInfo[macroKey];
            for (unsigned i = 0u, e = Args->getNumMacroArguments(); i != e; ++i) {
                if (const auto* Tok = Args->getUnexpArgument(i); Tok) {
                    // Handle address parameters using special case logic.
                    if (Tok->is(clang::tok::amp)) {
                        auto addressParam = mPP.getSpelling(*Tok);
                        auto specialToken = Tok + 1;
                        while (specialToken->isNot(clang::tok::eof)) {
                            addressParam += mPP.getSpelling(*specialToken);
                            ++specialToken;
                        }
                    } else if (Tok->isAnyIdentifier()) {
                        // @JC PreExpansion arguments are other unexpanded macros I think.
                        // This function is used to determine if a macro argument needs to be pre-expanded.
                        // If it can be proven that the argument won't be affected by pre-expansion, the
                        // function returns false. Otherwise, it conservatively returns true.
                        // @JC I think this means that if they do not need PreExpansion
                        // we will not have to go through the name/value substitution logic later.
                        if (Args->ArgNeedsPreexpansion(Tok, mPP)) {
                            // Parse the macro definition argument & save it for later substitution.
                            // as we will need this definition when MacroExpander is
                            // called later expanding this argument for real.
                            if (const auto ArgMI = mPP.getMacroInfo(Tok->getIdentifierInfo())) {
                                const auto ArgMacroName = Tok->getIdentifierInfo()->getName().str();
                                std::vector<clang::Token> Tokens;
                                // Loop over the replacement tokens.
                                Tokens.reserve(ArgMI->getNumTokens());
                                for (unsigned index = 0u; index < ArgMI->getNumTokens(); ++index) {
                                    Tokens.emplace_back(ArgMI->getReplacementToken(index));
                                }
                                std::string parameter;
                                for (const auto& t : Tokens) {
                                    parameter += mPP.getSpelling(t);
                                }
                                rMacroDefs[ArgMacroName] = parameter;
                            } else {
                                // @JC Don't thing this will be called
                                bool b = false;
                                rExpandedArgs.emplace_back(mPP.getSpelling(*Tok));
                            }
                        } else {
                            //
                            rExpandedArgs.emplace_back(mPP.getSpelling(*Tok));
                        }
                    } else {
                        rExpandedArgs.emplace_back(mPP.getSpelling(*Tok));
                    }
                }
            }

            // Expansion should have empty rMacroDefs
            if (rExpandedArgs.size() /* + rMacroDefs.size() */ == Args->getNumMacroArguments()) {
                std::map<std::string, std::string> macroParamInfo;
                for (auto index = 0u; index<macroArgNames.size(); ++index) {
                    macroParamInfo[macroArgNames[index]] = rExpandedArgs[index];
                }

                bool bStringification = false;
                const auto numTokens = MI->tokens().size();
                for (const auto next : MI->tokens()) {
                    if (next.isAnyIdentifier()) {
                        // Identifier can be a macro name or parameter or just a variable
                        const auto identifier = mPP.getSpelling(next);
                        //if (const auto ArgMI = mPP.getMacroInfo(next.getIdentifierInfo())) {
                        //    std::string expandedArg;
                        //    std::vector<clang::Token> fooTokens;
                        //    fooTokens.reserve(ArgMI->getNumTokens());
                        //    for (unsigned index = 0u; index < ArgMI->getNumTokens(); ++index) {
                        //        fooTokens.emplace_back(ArgMI->getReplacementToken(index));
                        //    }
                        //    for (const auto tok : fooTokens) {
                        //        expandedArg += mPP.getSpelling(tok);
                        //    }
                        //}

                        if (const auto iter = macroParamInfo.find(
                            identifier); iter != macroParamInfo.cend()) {
                            macroBody += iter->second;
                        } else {
                            // identifier can be the name of a macro - in which case we must expand it
                            macroBody += identifier;
                        }
                        if (bStringification) {
                            macroBody += '"';
                            bStringification = false;
                        } else {
                            macroBody += " ";
                        }
                    } else if (next.is(clang::tok::hash)) {
                        // turn on bStringification flag
                        macroBody += '"';
                        bStringification = true;
                    } else if (next.is(clang::tok::hashhash)) {
                        // do nothing (effectively) token pasting
                        macroBody = util::trim_str(macroBody);
                    } else if (next.isOneOf(clang::tok::comma, clang::tok::semi)) {
                        // do not trim the extra space after the above
                        macroBody += mPP.getSpelling(next);
                    } else if (next.isOneOf(
                        clang::tok::l_paren, clang::tok::r_paren, clang::tok::l_brace, clang::tok::r_brace,
                        clang::tok::l_square, clang::tok::r_square, clang::tok::colon, clang::tok::equal,
                        clang::tok::plus, clang::tok::minus, clang::tok::star, clang::tok::plusequal,
                        clang::tok::minusequal, clang::tok::minusminus, clang::tok::plusplus)) {
                        // Punctuation & a selection of popular operator separators
                        macroBody = util::trim_str(macroBody);
                        macroBody += mPP.getSpelling(next);
                    } else {
                        macroBody += mPP.getSpelling(next);
                        if (bStringification) {
                            macroBody += '"';
                            bStringification = false;
                        } else {
                            macroBody += " ";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // No more macro parameters to expand.  Assemble the
            // rewritten macro and update the source code.
            //if (bMacroBodyExpansion && (--rSpecialCounter <= 0)) {
            //    // TODO: this is where we should do the assembly/rewriting...
            //    std::string expandedMacro;
            //    for (const auto& next : rMacroArgValues) {
            //        expandedMacro += next;
            //        mRewriter.ReplaceText(expansionRange, expandedMacro);
            //    }
            //    // finished expanding this macro so delete it
            //    // from the list of macros to expand.
            //    gMacroExpansionInfo.erase(expansionRange.getBegin());
            //}
        } else {
            // I think there is always just one token in these single
            // objectLike macros that do not contain parameters.
            for (const auto Tok : MI->tokens()) {
                macroBody += mPP.getSpelling(Tok);
            }
            std::ranges::for_each(gMacroExpansionInfo, [&macroKey](auto& item) {
                MacroDefs& defs = item.second.second;
                if (auto it = std::ranges::find_if(defs, [&macroKey](const auto& def) {
                    return def.first == macroKey.first;
                }); it != defs.end()) {
                    item.second.first.emplace_back(it->second);
                    defs.erase(it);
                }
            });
            //mRewriter.ReplaceText(expansionRange, macroBody);
        }
    }
private:
    //! Source Location printer.
    std::string locStr(clang::SourceLocation loc) const {
        return loc.printToString(mPP.getSourceManager());
    }

    clang::Preprocessor& mPP;
    clang::Rewriter& mRewriter;
};

class MyFrontendAction : public clang::ASTFrontendAction {
public:
    [[nodiscard]] std::unique_ptr<clang::ASTConsumer> CreateASTConsumer(
        clang::CompilerInstance &CI, llvm::StringRef file) override {
        // Initialize the Rewriter, SourceManager and Language Options
        // from the provided compiler instance.
        mRewriter.setSourceMgr(CI.getSourceManager(), CI.getLangOpts());
        CI.getPreprocessor().addPPCallbacks(std::make_unique<
            MacroExpander>(CI.getPreprocessor(), mRewriter));
        return std::make_unique<clang::ASTConsumer>();
    }

    //! Outputs rewritten source to console.
    void EndSourceFileAction() override {
        mRewriter.getEditBuffer(mRewriter.getSourceMgr().
            getMainFileID()).write(llvm::outs());
    }
private:
    clang::Rewriter mRewriter;
};

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    auto ExpectedParser = CommonOptionsParser::create(argc, argv, MyToolCategory);
    if (!ExpectedParser) {
        llvm::errs() << ExpectedParser.takeError();
        return 1;
    }
    CommonOptionsParser &OptionsParser = ExpectedParser.get();
    ClangTool Tool(OptionsParser.getCompilations(), OptionsParser.getSourcePathList());
    return Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory<MyFrontendAction>().get());
}

